# How to save the state of the toogleButton on/off selection?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

Hello i have implemented the application based on the toggleButton selection. but while i close that application and then reopen it, it will get in to its default selection that is "off".
So can any budy tell mw what should i have to save the state of the toogleButton selection and perform some action based on that toggleButton selection state. . . 
Thanks.

Comment: Use SharedPreferences and store toggle button state on exit. Read more at http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/sharedPreferencesTutorial.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences.

```
tg = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

tg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

    if((tg.isChecked()))
        {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true); // value to store
                editor.commit();
        }
        else
        {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("tgpref", false); // value to store
                editor.commit();
        }
    }
});
```

And this is how to retrieve the values:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", true);  //default is true
if (tgpref = true) //if (tgpref) may be enough, not sure
{
  tg.setChecked(true);
}
else
{
  tg.setChecked(false);
}
```

I did not verify this code, but look at some examples on the net, it is easy!

Comment: Is it possible to save even if i close the activity or application and again start it ?

Comment: which mode i have to add during inserting the preference value ?

Comment: @iDroid Explorer Yes, this is the method to save your preferences and you can save them and read them after application is closed/restarted or whatever :)

Comment: I have done as u have explained. But if i close the activity and then again run it, the toogleButton still remains in its default condition "off" even if i have selected it as "on". Why it is happend like this?

Comment: It should be on, as it is set to true as default...please show us your code

Answer (score 3):

Use SharedPreferences like erdomester suggested, but I modified little bit his code. There's some unneeded conditions.

```
tg = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

tg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
       editor.putBoolean("tgpref", tg.isChecked()); // value to store
       editor.commit();
    }
});
```

And this is how to retrieve the values:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", true);  //default is true

tg.setChecked(tgpref);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the same, just a shorter and more transparent code :)

Comment: Why Should i have to use as default as true ?

Comment: You can put false there too. This is your choice what to set for default value.

Answer (score 3):

The best way, you can set tgbutton same

screen main

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Something.class);
intent.putExtra(BOOLEAN_VALUE, Boolean.valueOf((tvConfigBoolean.getText().toString())));
            startActivity(intent);
```

screen something

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
tbtConfigBoolean.setChecked((bundle
                    .getBoolean(MainActivity.BOOLEAN_VALUE)));
```

and save state

```
editor.putBoolean("BooleanKey", tbtConfigBoolean.isChecked());
        editor.commit();
```

good luck