# Trouble with using ToggleButton

Tags: android

I am using a toggle button in my applications settings page. The problem is, that once I turn the toggle button `on` and exit from the settings page and then again go to settings, it shows that toggle button is in `off` state. I want it in the `on` state until the user turns it `off`, even if the app is closed... Is it possible?

Comment: Use shared prefrence and pass statte of it to the shared prefrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for that with an `onCheckedChangedListener`.

Here's an example how I'm handling it for a CheckBox (should be equal to a ToggleButton, so it's untested, but should work!):

```
    ToggleButton mToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.mToggleButton);
    mToggleButton.setChecked(getSharedPreferences(mSharedPreferences, MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("dontShowAgain", false));
    mToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(mSharedPreferences, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("dontShowAgain", isChecked);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you are not saving the state of `ToggleButton`. Use `SharedPreference` to save the state of `ToggleButton` on Button click.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383752/how-to-save-the-state-of-the-tooglebutton-on-off-selection). This will help you