# How do we get and set same Toggle value while navigating from one screen(activity) to another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-togglebutton

My question is like in my activity 2 i have the screen like below.
[image]

I am toggling two or more toggle button (activity 2) and going back(arrow) to activity 1.
Now **My question is how to save those value when navigating from activity 1 to activity 2 again for the second time with two or more toggle off.**

Comment: You can use shared preferences to save toggle current status(true/false) on destroy of acticity 1. And read those preferences when you come to activity again.

Comment: But if i use Shared preference the value will be remain after killing the application.i want first time all are on that's why i can't use.@brijeshkumar

Comment: If u want first time all ON, set default value true in shared preferences while reading shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general Scenario in Android UI flow:
One way could be saving toggle state in Shared preferences as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383752/how-to-save-the-state-of-the-tooglebutton-on-off-selection):

You can save the toggle state in onPause() of Activity in  Shared preferences and restore the saved values in onResume() of the Activity

Comment: Thanks Nargis..i got the scenario and it worked for me@Nargis

Answer (score 0):

you can transfer infomation from activity1 to activity2 by using intent and bundle

-------------------Activity1---------------click

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class); 
intent.putExtra("Text", mText); 
intent.putExtra("TextColor", mTextColor); 
intent.putExtra("TextSize", mTextSize); 
intent.putExtra("TextBold", mTextBold); 

startActivity(intent);
```

-----------------------------Activity2--------------oncreate

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
mText = extras.getString("Text"); 
mTextColor = extras.getInt("TextColor"); 
mTextSize = extras.getFloat("TextSize"); 
mTextBold = extras.getBoolean("TextBold");
```

---

in your app, getBoolean is ok

Comment: i have to get toggle value from activity2 and back to the activity 1 (toolbar arrow button)and then again activity 1 to 2 then i want my last value updated values@fan Yimin